# Why do I get _state != _PlatformViewState.disposed is not true exception while updating HtmlView in flutter_web?

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to use HtmlView to show Google maps in my flutter_web application but unable to update the map reliably when markers change. It works fine half the time. Please take a look at the code below. I subscribe to marker changes in InitState(). When the marker data updates and listen returns I get get _state != _PlatformViewState.disposed exception every other time and it works every other time.

Looking into Flutter_web Platform View code it seems the previous HtmlView is disposed every time new HtmlView is created with a different ViewType. There seems to be something wrong with the redraw logic as this exception occurs right after the view is disposed. The build call after this exception successfully renders the HtmlView.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building HtmlView(dependencies: [Directionality], state:
_HtmlViewState#705f2):
Assertion failed: org-dartlang-app:///packages/flutter_web/src/services/platform_views.dart:789:12
_state != _PlatformViewState.disposed
is not true

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
dart:sdk_internal 4543:15                                        assertFailed
removeOnPlatformViewCreatedListener
package:flutter_web/…/services/platform_views.dart:789
package:flutter_web/src%5Crendering%5Cplatform_view.dart 471:21  set viewController
updateRenderObject (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cplatform_view.dart:752:17)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4670:12)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4055:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:5069:14)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3953:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
updateChildren (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4769:32)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:5186:17)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4164:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4164:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
updateChildren (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4769:32)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:5186:17)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4055:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4164:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4055:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:5069:14)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3953:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:5069:14)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4164:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
update (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:4055:5)
updateChild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2896:14)
performRebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3908:16)
rebuild (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:3713:5)
buildScope (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cframework.dart:2347:31)
drawFrame (package:flutter_web/src%5Cwidgets%5Cbinding.dart:710:49)
[_handlePersistentFrameCallback] (package:flutter_web/src%5Crendering%5Cbinding.dart:286:5)
[_invokeFrameCallback]
package:flutter_web/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1030
handleDrawFrame
package:flutter_web/…/scheduler/binding.dart:963
[_handleDrawFrame]
package:flutter_web/…/scheduler/binding.dart:874
<fn> (package:flutter_web_ui/src%5Cengine.dart:164:21)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

```
class Panics extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool selectOnly;
  final bool showAddButton;
  final bool boListGrid;
  final bool boShowAppBar;

  Panics(this.selectOnly,
      [this.showAddButton = true,
      this.boListGrid = true,
      this.boShowAppBar = true]);


  @override
  _PanicsState createState() =>
      _PanicsState(selectOnly, showAddButton, boListGrid, boShowAppBar);
}

class _PanicsState extends State<Panics> {
  final bool selectOnly;
  final bool showAddButton;
  final bool boListGrid;
  final bool boShowAppBar;
  String createdViewId = 'hello-world-html';
  String strMap;
  bool inProgress = true;
  // Subscription
  StreamSubscription subscription;
  List<fs.DocumentSnapshot> panics;

  Map<String, bool> boShowGrid;
  List<fs.DocumentReference> isSelected;
  final key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  // final _foldingCellKey = GlobalKey<SimpleFoldingCellState>();

  _PanicsState(
      this.selectOnly, this.showAddButton, this.boListGrid, this.boShowAppBar);



@override
  void initState() {
    debugPrint("PANICS: initState");
    // TODO: implement initState
    isSelected = List<fs.DocumentReference>();
    boShowGrid = Map<String, bool>();
    showPanics(null);
    fs.Query ref;
        if (Globals.role == Role.Manager) {
      // Make a reference to firestore
      ref = firestore()
          .collection('locations')
          .where("hotelId", "==", Globals.hotelID);
    } else {
      // Make a reference to firestore
      ref = firestore()
          .collection('locations')
          .where("userId", "==", Globals.userId);
    }

    ref = ref.where("status", "==", "new");

      subscription = ref.onSnapshot.listen((data) {
        showPanics(data.docs);
      });
    super.initState();
  }


  void showPanics(List<fs.DocumentSnapshot> panics) {
    String markers = "";
    String latlng = "var myLatLng = {lat: 41.850033, lng: -87.6500523}";
    DateTime max = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(0);
    fs.GeoPoint lastPanicPosition;

if (panics != null) {
     panics.forEach((data) {
      Panic panic = Panic.fromSnapshot(data);

      String strIcon = (panic.status == 'new')?"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png":"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png";
      String marker =
          "var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(${panic.position.latitude}, ${panic.position.longitude})," 
            + "map: map, icon:"$strIcon", title: '${Globals.globals.getUserName(panic.userId)} needs help!'});\n";
      markers += marker;
      DateTime time = panic.timeStamp;
            if (time.compareTo(max) > 0 ) {
        max = time;
        lastPanicPosition = panic.position;
      }
   });
         latlng = "var myLatLng = {lat: ${lastPanicPosition.latitude}, lng: ${lastPanicPosition.longitude}}";
}

debugPrint("Panics: showPanic markers = $markers");
debugPrint("Panics: showPanic latlng = $latlng");

    String createdViewUpdate = DateTime.now().toString();
    rootBundle.loadString('map.html').then((value) {
    String strMapUpdate = value.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'var myLatLng = {lat: 41.850033, lng: -87.6500523}'), latlng);
      strMapUpdate = strMapUpdate.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'markers'), markers);
      debugPrint ("Panics strMapUpdate =: $strMapUpdate");
      ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
          createdViewId,
          (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
            ..width = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 400).toString()
            ..height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString()
            ..srcdoc = strMapUpdate
            ..style.border = 'none');
    });
if ((panics != null)&&(mounted)) {
    setState(() {
      inProgress = false;
      this.createdViewId = createdViewUpdate;
      this.panics = panics;
    });
}
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  debugPrint("Panics build");
    return (((Globals.globals == null) || (Globals.documentID == null))
        //Uncomment this to use roomList
        //    ||(Globals.roomList.isEmpty)
        )
        ? Scaffold(body: Text("Loading..."))
        : (selectOnly)
            ? Scaffold(
                key: key,
                appBar: AppBar(title: Text(Globals.hotelName + ":Alerts")),
                body: _buildBody(context),
              )
            : (showAddButton)
                ? Scaffold(
                    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: "panic",
                      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                      mini: true,
                      child: Icon(Icons.person),
                      onPressed: () => setState(() {
                        _deletePanics(context);
                      }),
                    ),
                    floatingActionButtonLocation:
                        FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
                    appBar: (boShowAppBar)
                        ? AppBar(
                            title: Text(
                                (boListGrid) ? "Alerts list" : "Alerts grid"))
                        : null,
                    body: Row (
                            children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 400,
                                      child: HtmlView(
                                      viewType: createdViewId,
                                      onPlatformViewCreated: _onPlatformViewCreated,
                                      )),
                                  Container(
                                      width: 400,
                                      child: _buildBody(context),
                                  )
                            ]
                    )
                  )
                : (boShowAppBar)
                    ? Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Panics")),
                        body: _buildBody(context),
                      )
                    : Scaffold(
                        body: _buildBody(context),
                      );
  }
```

Comment: I got this too, but resolved it by not reloading a widget until re-creating the htmlview. Did you log it on flutter?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't logged it on flutter since I couldn't find a way to submit issues for flutter web. But I got it to work well using the approach in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to workaround this issue by moving the call to   ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory to the build function just before HtmlView gets built. I had to delay the reload of HtmlView by wrapping it into a FutureBuilder widget to allow for the build function time to fetch the marker information from Firebase. See code below

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("Panics: build: boShowAppBar = $boShowAppBar ");
    //showPanics(null);
    return (((Globals.globals == null) || (Globals.documentID == null))
        //Uncomment this to use roomList
        //    ||(Globals.roomList.isEmpty)
        )
        ? Scaffold(body: Text("Loading..."))
        : (selectOnly)
            ? Scaffold(
                key: key,
                appBar: AppBar(title: Text(Globals.hotelName + ":Alerts")),
                body: _buildBody(context),
              )
            : Scaffold(
                    floatingActionButton: (showAddButton) ? FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: "panic",
                      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                      mini: true,
                      child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                      tooltip: "Delete selected",
                      onPressed: () => setState(() {
                        _deletePanics(context);
                      }),
                    ):null,
                    floatingActionButtonLocation:
                        FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
                    appBar: (boShowAppBar)
                        ? AppBar(
                            title: Text(
                                (boListGrid) ? "Alerts list" : "Alerts grid"),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                                        _deletePanics(context);
                                      }),
                                  child: Text("Delete selected",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
                            ],
                          )
                        : null,
                    body: Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 400,
                        child: _buildBody(context),
                      ),
                        Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 400,
                        child: FutureBuilder(
                          future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)),
                          builder: (c,s) => (s.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)?showMap():Container(),)
                      )
                    ]));
  }
  Widget showMap() {
    debugPrint("PANICS: showMap()");
    showPanics(this.panics);
    return HtmlView(      viewType: createdViewId,
                          onPlatformViewCreated: _onPlatformViewCreated,
                        );
  }
```

Comment: where is 'registerViewFactory'? it's not in this code.